# How can I hit my iis express site from my android devices?

Tags: android, iis-express

I have a site running under IIS Express, I added the following to my `applicationHost.config`

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49223:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49223:myMachineName" />
```

So now, from another laptop on my local wireless network I can hit `http://myMachineName:49223/` and see my site without issue.

**However**, if I hit the same URL from an android device (tried on `Galaxy S` and `Galaxy S2`) on the same local wireless network I get the standard android *Web page not available*.

How can I hit my iis express site from my android devices? Any suggestions for debugging this issue gratefully recieved :(

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: Okeydokes :) 

So what to do then when your question is relevant in more than one SE?

Comment: Please do read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience stems from lack of native NetBIOS/NetBT support.

When your windows computer is trying to resolve single label names, one of the steps is to issue a broadcast request for the particular name, and see if any nodes in the local subnet answers to that name. The resolution sequence goes something like this:

- Try to resolve using the hosts file
- Try using WINS
- Try issuing NetBIOS broadcast
- Default to DNS name resolution

In Android, name resolution goes like this:

- Try to resolve using the hosts file
- Default to DNS name resolution

So you would probably have to add an entry to the hosts file on your phone to make it work.

The Android hosts file is located in `/system/etc/hosts` (sym-link `/etc/hosts`). AFAIK you'll need root access to edit/overwrite the hosts file

Comment: Once rooted, i used this to edit the host files https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treb.hosts&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50cmViLmhvc3RzIl0. and then all was well.